# Why when I pass a Lambda expressin Func thats give me an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, lambda

When I pass call a Generic Method that return A Func and pass in parameter of the Where, that's dosen't work. (System.InvalidOperationException: Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.)
The error is when I want to get the Role information. 
For the Role, I need to perform a Where Clause Expression EX: (p => p.LangID == 1)

**This code dosen't Work**

In the repository

```
public Func<T, bool> GetLmbLang<T>() where T:class,IBaseGenericTxt
    {
        int lang = -1;
        lang = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"]);
        return (p => p.LangID == lang);
    }
```

In the controller

```
                var ViewModel = _db.Contacts.Where(a=> a.IsActive == true).Select(a => new ContactListViewModel { 
                    ContactID = a.ContactID,
                    ContactName = a.ContactName,
                    Role = a.ContactType.ContactTypeTexts.Where(repGeneric.GetLmbLang<ContactTypeText>()).Select(af => af.Txt).FirstOrDefault(),
                    CompanyType = a.Supplier.SupplierName,
                    Addr = a.Address ,
                    Email = a.ContactEmail,
                    Phone = a.ContactPhone
                }).ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < ViewModel.Count(); i++)
                {
                    Response.Write(ViewModel.ElementAt(i).ContactID + "<br />");
                }
```

**This code WORK**

```
 int lang = -1;
            lang = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Language"]);
            var ViewModel = _db.Contacts.Where(a=> a.IsActive == true).Select(a => new ContactListViewModel { 
                ContactID = a.ContactID,
                ContactName = a.ContactName,
                Role = a.ContactType.ContactTypeTexts.Where(p => p.LangID == lang).Select(af => af.Txt).FirstOrDefault(),
                CompanyType = a.Supplier.SupplierName,
                Addr = a.Address ,
                Email = a.ContactEmail,
                Phone = a.ContactPhone
            }).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < ViewModel.Count(); i++)
            {
                Response.Write(ViewModel.ElementAt(i).ContactID + "<br />");
            }
```

My ContactListViewModel

```
public class ContactListViewModel
    {
        public int ContactID { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string CompanyType { get; set; }
        public Address Addr { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

**My List View**

```
 ..... Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<mvcinfosite.ViewModels.ContactListViewModel>>" %>
 <table class="genTable">


    <% for (int i = 0;i < Model.Count; i++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink(item.ContactName, "Edit", new { id=item.ContactID }) %>
            </td>

            <td>
                <%: item.Role  %>
            </td>

            <td>
                <%: item.Company %>
            </td>

            <td>
                <%: item.CompanyType  %>
            </td>

            <td>
                <%: GlobalHelper.GetAddress(item.Addr) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.Email %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.Phone %>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>
```

Comment: very confusing code. your doing `_db.Contacts.ToList()` (basically grabbing ALL the contacts), then doing *another* query to Contacts where they're active, doing `AsQueryable()` (which is redundant), but the main problem i think is your tryint to do inline queries in your projection (ie the Role property). Maybe if you explain **what your trying to do**, we can help you write a better query.

Comment: I want to fill a table with all my active contact. You're right about AsQueryable(). I Made a lot of test, and just forgot to remove that for my post. Role is a string, I need to get this value from my contact type texts. I'll make an update to my original post to add details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As naasking points out, you need to use an Expression of a Func instead of a straight Func:

```
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetLmbLang<T>() where T:class,IBaseGenericTxt
{
    int lang = -1;
    lang = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"]);
    return (p => p.LangID == lang);
}
```

**Edit**

Ah, yes, well the problem is that your function doesn't actually know what class it's working with at compile time: it only knows that it's a class, and it implements IBaseGenericTxt. So when you say `p.LangId`, that part of the expression is calling IBaseGenericTxt.LangId, and not ContactTypeText.LangId.

You'll need to build your own expression tree in order to get this to work right. Something like this:

```
var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(paramExpr, "LangId"),
        Expression.Constant(lang)),
    paramExpr);
```

**Edit 2**

Two things:

1. Because LINQ to Entities will try to take anything in a query expression and convert it to a SQL statement, you have to be careful not to go calling methods in the middle of your query. You'll want to call the GetLmbLang method first and store its value in a variable to use in the query.
2. As you point out in your comment, because the ContactTypeTexts property does not implement IQueryable, this gets particularly tricky. You have three options as far as I can tell:

   1. Create your entire select statement as an expression tree. This is very annoying and error-prone.
   2. Use Joe Albari's [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to "Compile" and "Expand" your query. LinqKit will traverse the expression tree and build a new tree wherein your query Expression is converted to its equivalent Func.
   3. Go back to your data context rather than using the ContactTypeTexts property.

Personally, I would probably go with the last option, like this:

```
var lambdaLang = repGeneric.GetLmbLang<ContactTypeText>();
var ViewModel = _db.Contacts
    .Where(a=> a.IsActive == true)
    .Select(a => new ContactListViewModel { 
    ContactID = a.ContactID,
    ContactName = a.ContactName,
    Role = _db.ContactTypeTexts
        .Where(ct => ct.ContactType.Contacts.Any(
            c => c.ContactId == a.ContactId)
        .Where(lambdaLang)
        .Select(af => af.Txt).FirstOrDefault(),
    CompanyType = a.Supplier.SupplierName,
    Addr = a.Address ,
    Email = a.ContactEmail,
    Phone = a.ContactPhone
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, I try that, but that give me 2 errors . Error 1 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<myproject.Models.ContactTypeText>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<myproject.Models.ContactTypeText>' C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myproject\myproject\Controllers\ContactController.cs 35 24 myproject

Comment: seconde one is : Error 2 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<myproject.Models.ContactTypeText>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myproject\myproject\Controllers\ContactController.cs 35 24 myproject

Comment: @Jean-Francois: voyez le mise-a-jour ci-dessus.

Comment: Nice, I Understand what you're saying, but that dosen't work. The problem appear because I made a subquery on contactypetext . If I apply the function directly on the entity like . _db.ContactTypeTexts.Where(repGeneric.GetLmbLang<ContactTypeText>()) , thats work. If I'm doing the same thing in a Select like _db.Contacts.Select(a => new { SingleContactType =  a.ContactType.ContactTypeTexts.Where(repGeneric.GetLmbLang<ContactTypeText>())})  Thats fail..   (MERCI BEAUCOUP POUR TON AIDE @StriplingWarrior)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior. Thanks for your help. Great explanation. A Lot of effort to support me in this issue. I Realy appreciate all you do here. Be sure, if I can help you in something, I'll do my best to help you.

Comment: @Jean-Francois: Just pay it forward.

Answer (score 1):

The latter code works because the C# compiler converts it into an expression tree, ie. System.Linq.Expression, whereas your original code was compiled as a Func. Linq to SQL as currently designed cannot process the Func, only expression trees.